# navigate a table in selenium

Tags: jquery, selenium-rc

Suppose I have a simple table, like this:

```
Smith    |  Select
Jones    |  Select
Johnson  |  Select
```

And I need to write a Selenium test to select the link corresponding to Jones.  I can make it click the "Select" in the 2nd row, but I would rather have it find where "Jones" is and click the corresponding "Select".  I'm thinking I may need to incorporate JQuery to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an xpath expression like "//tc[.//text() = 'Jones']/../tc[2]/a" which looks for a table cell whose text contents are 'Jones' and then naviagates up to that cells parent, selects the second table cell of that parent, and then a link inside the second table cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use jQuery, here is some information:

- First you can read the jquery from a jquery.js or jquery.min.js file.
- Then using execute_script(jquery) to enable jquery dynamically.
- Now you can interact with jquery.

here is some code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox

with open('jquery.min.js', 'r') as jquery_js: #read the jquery from a file
    jquery = jquery_js.read()
    browser.execute_script(jquery)  #active the jquery lib

#now you can write some jquery code then execute_script them
js = """
    var str = "div#myPager table a:[href=\\"javascript:__doPostBack('myPager','%s')\\"]"
    console.log(str)
    var $next_anchor = $(str);
    if ($next_anchor.length) {
        return $next_anchor.get(0).click(); //do click and redirect
    } else {
        return false;
    }""" % str(25) 

success = browser.execute_script(js)
if success == False:
    break
```